# Install Workflow Manager on which Servers

Tags: workflow

I would like to know which SharePoint servers I should install workflow manager. do I need to install the wf manager on a server that doesn't have sharepoint? or do I need to install it on web servers with sharepoint installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install workflow manager on non sharepoint server or you can install it on sharepoint server as well. It's depend upon resources(server, hardware etc).

Important thing is, if you have more than one server...if you install workflow manager on one server then install workflow manager client on all remaining sharepoint server.

For more information please the below [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx).

Comment: thanks Waqas, so I don't need to install it on all sharepoint servers?

Comment: If you go through the technet, they describe the 4 combinations and pick one which u like....if wfm is on non sharepoint server then you have to install workflow manager client only on all sharepoint server.